# In QEMU Bitbake native Environment where to find the make analyze output

Tags: makefile, native, qemu, bitbake

Iam Running my project in the QEMU Setup. Changed the bitbake recipe for a component with native to support "make analyze" and "make check".

```
Issued Below commands:

bitbake -c clean <component_name-native>
bitbake -c compile <component_name-native>
bitbake -c analyze <component_name-native>
bitbake -c check <component_name-native>
```

Running the commands in the location

```
rvea@rtscl076[/data/users/project/poky/build]
```

No Errors from the above commands.

My Question is where to find the analyze output logs stored for the component. so that i can correct the errors found for the particular component.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, are you sure that those commands were really executed?
Try the -f (force) option to ensure that:

```
bitbake -c <task> -f <target>
```

Secondly, check out the reference manual which provides information about where you can find log files for each task and some tips on debugging: [Yocto Project Reference Manual - Debugging Build Failures](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#usingpoky-debugging-taskfailures)

Comment: Yes iam Sure its executed.. that ref manual didnt say the location for analyze/check logs. i also want to know the gcovr results too in BB...

Comment: For logs for particular component try searching for: ${WORKDIR}/temp/log.do_taskname.pid. Where _taskname_ will represent the real task such as _do_compile_.WORKDIR is defined as: ${TMPDIR}/work/${MULTIMACH_TARGET_SYS}/${PN}/${EXTENDPE}${PV}-${PR}. Let's omit the details now and quote the ref manual: `As an example (...) suppose your recipe is named foo_1.3.0-r0.bb. In this case, the work directory the build system uses to build the package would be as follows: poky/build/tmp/work/qemux86-poky-linux/foo/1.3.0-r0` Then just go to temp/ directory and check the logs.